# How can I extract CQT from audio with sampling rate 8000Hz (librosa)

Tags: python, librosa

How can I extract CQT from audio with sampling rate 8000 Hz (librosa)

I wrote following codes.

```
sound_clip, s = librosa.load(fn, sr=8000)
cqtpec = librosa.cqt(y=sound_clip, sr=s)
```

But there was an error.

```
librosa.util.exceptions.ParameterError: Filter pass-band lies beyond Nyquist
```

I wanna extract CQT feature from audio with sampling rate 8000 Hz.

Answer (score 3):

Use a lower `n_bins` or a lower `fmin`. With the default `fmin` of 32.7Hz (musical C1), `n_bins` = 84, and `bins_per_octave` = 12, the highest bin falls 7 octaves higher, at 4186Hz (C8), but with a sampling rate of 8000Hz you can only deal with frequencies up to 4000Hz, so if you keep `fmin` the same, `n_bins` needs to be no more than 83.